# celery worker with gevent pool always uses default config

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

when I try to run celery worker with gevent pool it uses the default broker URL (amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//).

```
celery worker --workdir /mnt/src/ --config worker.celeryconfig -l debug -Q io_tasks -c 200 -P gevent --logfile=/var/log/celery.io_tasks.log --hostname=io_tasks.%h --without-heartbeat

[config]
 > app:         default:0x7f449e691cf8 (.default.Loader)
 > transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
 > results:     disabled://
 > concurrency: 200 (gevent)
 > task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
[queues]
 > io_tasks         exchange=io_tasks(direct) key=io_tasks
```

Here's a part of worker/celeryconfig.py

```
# actual dockerized rabbitmq broker url (amqp://admin:**@172.17.0.3:5672//)
broker_url = "amqp://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/".format(
    user=os.environ['RABBITMQ_ENV_RABBITMQ_USER'],
    password=os.environ['RABBITMQ_ENV_RABBITMQ_PASS'],
    host=os.environ['RABBITMQ_PORT_5672_TCP_ADDR'],
    port=os.environ['RABBITMQ_PORT_5672_TCP_PORT']
)
```

- python 3.6
- celery 4.0.2
- gevent 1.2.1

Comment: It's not clear from your question how you are attempting to override the config settings for broker_url.

Comment: @postoronnim it's in the bottom of my code block (**broker_url** in worker/celeryconfig.py. **--config worker.celeryconfig**). did you mean this?

Comment: What I meant is that I saw the url definition but I am not seeing where you are overwriting the default. At the bottom, you are showing a portion of a script that tries to assign the url dynamically. You can use the ConfigParser module for it.

Comment: @postoronnim I am overwriting the default broker_url in worker/celeryconfig.py. --config worker.celeryconfig should overwrite the default celery config

Comment: You are invoking the worker from command line, which is not seeing your script. Put everything in the script, and run the script only from command line.

Comment: ..but the same command with prefork option (-P prefork) works as expected